# getting error while using count in string "BANANA" to find "ANA" as substring using str.count() inbuild function of python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

when executing the command in python

```
str="BANANA"
print(str.count("ANA"))
```

give answer as 1.

but real answer would be 2. how to solve this

Comment: It works as intended. From the help of `str.count` Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in string S[start:end]

Answer (score 1):

It's true that this might be misleading most tutorial sites say that count returns the number of occurences in the string, it should actually say it returns the nnumber of non-overlapping occurences in the string